Breaker for Sub Panel
I need to run power to my wood shop what Size Breaker Should I use in my Main Breaker Box to run UF-B 6/3 to a Sub Panel in my shop?

The gauge(6) should be safe with a 50 amp breaker.  The real question is if the main panel can take it.  A load calculation should/must be done.

A load calculation is done first to see how much unused power is available.  That will give the maximum size of the breaker that can be used.  The breaker size will give the minimum gauge wire that can be used.  Bigger wire gauge is good, smaller wire gauge is very bad.

#6 NM is 55A.   I would use 2-2-2-4 AL.
It is cheaper and almost twice the amps at 90A.   Alternately consider 6-6-6-6 Al at 50A.

@crip659 Subpanels are not loads. It’s always legal to send anything up to the entire service size to a subpanel, regardless of the existing loads in the main panel (with appropriate wire of course). The load calculation will dictate what loads can be added.

Your local inspector is likely going to require (NEC Article 220) load calcs to determine the load your shop will be adding to your panel and if your panel has capacity.
UF cable is limited by 340.80 to the 60°C column of Table 310.16, which is 55A for #6 copper.
If your calculated load and available capacity allow the 55A maximum allowed on UF #6 copper you will find that 55A is not a 240.6 standard breaker size, so 240.4 allows you to bump up to the next larger breaker size.
